# with build id not found, continuing with out symbols, encountered with linux perf on cross platform

Tags: android, linux, performancecounter, perf, flamegraph

i have a simple program whose performance is to be measured on a arm cortex a7 machine with linux 3.10 and perf tool 3.4 version

program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i=0;
void main2(void)
{
for(i=0;i<20000;i++);
}
void main3(void)
{
for(i=0;i<30000;i++);
}
void main4(void)
{
for(i=0;i<40000;i++);
}
void main5(void)
{
for(i=0;i<50000;i++);
}
main(void)
{
printf("Main2\n");
main2();
printf("Main3\n");
main3();
printf("Main4\n");
main4();
printf("Main5\n");
main5();
}
```

perf tool data vizualized using flame graph

```
#perf record -F 5000 -g a.out
#perf script 1>temp1 2>temp2
#stackcollapse-perf.pl temp1 > temp
#flamegraph.pl temp > temp.svg
```

temp.svg is below

[image]

so my doubt here is what are the unknown traces why would they occur, the reason why i increased my sampling rate to 5000 is i am not able to view main2 and main3 if its around 99

**UPDATE**:
the above `unknown` symbols are because the perf doesnt know our symbols on a cross platform, so the graph just puts unknown in the hex address of unknown symbols, so its suggested to provide vmlinux file as input to its `report`, even after provided it. i have observed the report of the `perf`  throws a error along with the report

```
[trout_fm] with build id 71f5660a1b9cba292e6bb94a5ba3ac20644852dd not found, continuing without symbols
```

this is because my vmlinux build id and the buildid with perf.data are not matching ? i think so !

if so, from where did the perf.data get the build id any way ?

provided i have carefully flashed the same image and using same vmlinux 
`perf report -k vmlinux`

can any one please help me ? to overcome this issue .

Comment: How do you compile your program ?

Comment: i compile it using the `arm-linux-gnueabi` cross compiler, as my executable is supposed to run on the cortex a7 machine, after application is built, i push it to the device and run it there by logging to the device

Comment: have you checked your optimization options to be sure that the compiler is not removing away your functions ?

Comment: Your binary needs debuginfo. Try "-g" option of gcc

Comment: yes i have mentioned -g option too, i have also found that the hex address are being displayed when i do perf report, which is because the perf is not able to trace/map addresses with symbol table, so i have given  vmlinux file as a input with option -k, still then also the same problem repeats why so ??